# what case is "Дурака" in "Дурака ему"

Tags: грамматика

what case is "Дурака" in "Дурака ему"

Comment: This could be genitive or accusative, but it's impossible to tell without the context. Could you please provide some context?

Comment: I can only guess that OP refers to "Дурака ему, дурака, старому подлецу!" from "Ревизор" by Гоголь, when the mayor blames himself for being tricked.

Comment: Yes, this is the only citation National Corpus finds: *Анна Андреевна.* Но этого не может быть, Антоша: он обручился с Машенькой...

*Городничий (в сердцах).* Обручился! Кукиш с маслом - вот тебе обручился! Лезет мне в глаза с обрученьем!.. (В исступлении.) Вот смотрите, смотрите, весь мир, все христианство, все смотрите, как одурачен городничий! Дурака ему, дурака, старому подлецу! (Грозит самому себе кулаком.) Эх ты, толстоносый! Сосульку, тряпку принял за важного человека!

Answer (score 4):

I guess in the above-mentioned quote from Гоголь there's actually an ellipsis from "сказать дурака":

> ...все смотрите, как одурачен городничий! (Скажите) дурака ему, дурака, старому подлецу

"сказать дурака кому-л." (lit. to say fool to someone) is an obsolete form of "назвать кого-л. дураком" (to call someone a fool), so it's accusative.